# Do any two objects have an infinite number of properties that are shared or divided by?

Tags: epistemology

It is argued, here, in this SEP article (https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/natural-properties/), that this is true. I'm having trouble making sense of this.

Assume you have a cup and a tree. How can we say that they share infinitely many properties? This hinges upon the assumption that we can even come up with an infinite set of properties. But a property is usually constructed meaningfully. As in "being an even number" might be a property but "waefiojerf" clearly is not. The latter is meaningless. How can we say that the set of conceivable properties is infinite?

Secondly, clearly a cup doesn't share the property of having people drink from it with a tree. As such, we can confidently say that that is a property that divides them. But a cup and a bottle share that property. So out of all possibly conceivable properties, we know that this one isn't shared. How can we then confidently say that they share the same number of properties, i.e. an infinite amount.

Comment: Both have names. Both names have properties. Both names properties have properties. Both names properties properties have properties...

Comment: @thinkingman I think Kant goes over this sort of notion when he discusses the *ens realissimum*, he says something about an object being determinable by every pair of incompatible/positive-and-negative properties. So a cup and a tree might not share many positive properties, but they share "not being zebras," for example, etc.

Comment: You can tap a maple tree and drink straight from the tap. So cups and trees share the property that you can drink from them.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the property "is non-identical to unicorns". Surely both our cup and tree aren't identical to unicorns: they truly have the property "not identical to unicorns".

Now consider the property "not located on Mars". Surely both our cup and tree have this property.

More generally, consider the property schema "is not-identical to β" where β is any arbitrary different object: by reiterating this over infinitely many things, say, the natural numbers (hopefully, the cup and tree *aren't* natural numbers), then these are all properties that the cup & tree have in common.

Any sufficiently abundant conception of universals will lead you here but arguably this is provable from sparse ones as well.